# How to show pyspark docstrings in pycharm

Tags: pyspark, pycharm

Environment

- pycharm 2016.3.2
- python 2.7
- pip install pyspark in venv

Some documents works well, 
[image: XXX]

But others are not work
[image]

It is very wired, how to fix this?